# best free software to make/open rar files

Tags: macos, mac

Which is the best software to open/make rar files in Mac OS?

I am new to Mac and I want to open rar files.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[The Unarchiver](http://www.apple.com/downloads/macosx/system_disk_utilities/theunarchiver.html) will open them and almost any other compression format.

Comment: You also have unrarx http://www.unrarx.com/ but only for decompression, I would also like to know of an app to compress as .rar, which your post doesn't say...

Comment: @jackJoe I don't know any way to make rar files on the Mac, but some of the other answers have ideas.

Answer (score 5):

If you are comfortable using **terminal** app, then you can uncompress a **rar** file without installing any software on your mac book. Open the **terminal** application on mac and go to the location where your **rar** file is and type the following command (replace the compressedfilename with actual file):

```
tar xvf compressedfilename.rar
```

The above command will uncompress all files from the compressed **rar** file in current directory. You can type **ls** command to view the list of files, or use Finder to view all extracted files.

x - extract the the compress file,
v - verbose,
f - name of archive file

Comment: Are you sure that the standard tar command is able to extract a rar file?

Comment: @nohillside, I just tested extracting a **RAR** _archive_ under **macOS Catalina** using its built-in `tar` _command_ and it worked without issue. The **RAR** _archive_ in this test was not encrypted. I think I read somewhere along the way that **RAR** support was added to `tar` in **macOS**, not sure where I read it or what version it was first included.

Comment: @user3439894 Well, there is a reference to `librar` in `https://opensource.apple.com/source/gnutar/gnutar-455/gnutar/configure.auto.html` (even though librar itself isn't there). But it's not even mentioned in the man page

Answer (score 4):

[The Unarchiver](http://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/the-unarchiver/id425424353?mt=12) is probably the most highly regarded piece of OS X software out there for expanding archives.

[SimplyRar](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/21430/simplyrar) is free and can help you create RAR files, but the developer doesn't seem to be active any more. Not sure how well it works in the latest OS X release.

[RarMachine](http://www.candyware.net/RarMachine.html) from CandyWare is $8 and can do RAR archive creation. That's pretty close to free.

[Entropy](http://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/entropy/id437151949?mt=12) looks pretty snazzy. But $18.

[RAR is a proprietary, closed source format](http://www.rarlab.com/). You usually have to license it to build a tool that creates RAR files. They make the unarchiving available for free because it helps them sell licenses for archiving. Hence RAR-*creation* utilities rarely being free, but unarchivers being available for free.

Comment: I just tried SimplyRar with OS X 10.5.8 and it works great!

Answer (score 0):

I just found this application: http://archiverapp.com. Looks promising!

Answer (score 0):

Default Terminal is also the best tool to open `rar` & `zip`. If you are comfortable with the **terminal** then try it without download any third party software in Mac.

#### For `zip` files

In the terminal (at `.zip` location):

```
unzip <filename>
```

---

#### For `rar` files

Try using Homebrew...

In a terminal type:

```
brew install rar
```

Now to use it just navigate to your file directory and type:

- To view the `rar` file:

```
unrar l <filename>
```

- To extract the `rar` file in the same location:

```
unrar x <filename>
```

- To extract the `rar` file in the desired location:

```
unrar x <filename>
```

In case you face any permission issue: **Developer cannot be verified**.
`'rar'` cannot be opened because the developer cannot be verified.
**Follow this process:**
Open System Preferences -> Security and Privacy -> General -> Click the lock to make changes.